# Docker Nginx: host not found in upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy

I have my docker app running in the aws EC2 instance, and I am currently trying to map the app to the external IP address using Nginx. Here is a snap shot of the containers that I have running:

[image]

My test-app is a fairly simple app that displays a static html website. And I deployed it using the following command:

`docker run -d --name=test-app test-app`

The nginx-proxy has the following *proxy.conf*

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://test-app;
  }
}
```

Here is the Dockerfile for the nginx proxy:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

COPY proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

nginx-proxy is run using the following command:
`docker run -d -p 80:80 --name=nginx-proxy nginx-proxy`

However, the nginx container never runs, and here the error log I get

```
2020/03/27 15:55:19 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "test-app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:5
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "test-app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While your two containers are both running and you have properly exposed the ports required for the NGINX container. You have not exposed any ports for the `test-app` container. The NGINX container has no way of talking to it. Exposing ports directly with `docker run` would likely defeat the point of using a reverse proxy in your situation. So instead, what you should do in this situation is create a [Network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) for both of your Docker containers and then add them to it. Then they will be able to communicate with one-another over a bridge. For example:

```
docker network create example
docker run -d --network=example --name=test-app test-app
docker run -d -p 80:80 --network=example --name=nginx-proxy nginx-proxy
```

Now that you have both of your pods on the same network, Docker will enable DNS-based [service discovery](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) between them by container name and you will be able to resolve them from each other. You can test connectivity like so: `docker exec -it nginx-proxy ping test-app`. Well, that is provided `ping` is installed in that Docker container.

Comment: I added the network and it worked. Also, thanks for the tips to test connectivity.